# A Coupon's collector look a like problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, expected-value, coupon-collector

The pub Gosset’s Paradise serves $N ≥ 1$ different brands of beer. Each time a drink is ordered, one of the brands is served uniformly at random. John wants to sample each brand at least once. Let $X_n ∈ {1,...,N}$ denote the brand that was served at the $nth$ order. Let $E_n ⊂ {1,...,N}$ be the random set of different brands that John has been served after his $nth$ order.

Let $T_r$ $:=$ $inf${$n$ $≥$ $1$ : |$E_n$| = $r$} denote the first time when John has sampled $r ∈ {1,...,N}$ different brands.

Finally, set $D_r$ $:=$ $T_r$ $−$ $T_{r−1}$ and $T_0$ $:=$ $0$.

Let $1$ $≤$ $r$ $<$ $N$ and $d_1$,...,$d_r$ $∈$ {${1,2,...}$}

The question is as follows: Let $d$ $∈$ {${1,2,...}$} and $I$ $⊂$ {${1,...,N}$} with $|I|$ $=$ $r$. 
 Show that for every $i$ $\notin$ $I$ we have

$\mathbb P(A|B)$ $=$ $(\frac{r}{N})^{d-1}$ $*$ $\frac{1}{N}$,

where we take

$A = \{T_{r + 1} = n + d\} \cap\,\{ X_{n + d} = i \} $ and $B=\{ D_j = d_j \text{ for $1\le j \le r$}\} \cap \{\Xi_n = I\}$

and $n$ $:=$ $d_1$ $+$ $···$ $+$ $d_r$.

After that, I have to show that $D_{r+1}$ is geometrically distributed with parameter $1$ $-$ $\frac{r}{N}$.

I know this question looks like the Coupon's collector problem, but I have a lot of trouble finding an answer to this question due to all the "variables" and information.

Comment: I suspect that conditional probability requires $i \not \in I$ to be meaningful.  What it seems to say is that given (a) that the arrival times of the past $r$ novel beers were $d_1, d_2,\ldots,d_r$ and (b) that the set of $r$ past novel beers were the elements of $I$, the probability that the next novel beer arrives at time $n+d$ (i.e. $d_1+ d_2+\cdots+d_r+d$) and is of type $i$ is $\left(\frac r N \right)^{d-1} \frac1N$

Comment: The easy handwaving way to get this result this is that once you have seen $r$ types of beer, the probability of seeing the next novel beer after exactly a further $d$ tries is that you only see familiar beers in $d-1$ tries and then see a novel beer on the $d$th try.  You may be expected to say rather more than this

Comment: I am stil nog able to find the answer. Is there a way you van help me further?